# H2 - Postgres mode support net data type

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, h2

I have a DAO that is accessing a Postgres database. I want to use H2 for my unit tests - everything works great except that the table I am operating on has a column with `inet` datatype - so I get the exception

> Unknown data type: "inet"; SQL statement: delete from table where id = ? and ip_address = ?::inet [50004-200]

Been a while since I've used H2 - I've set Postgres mode for the connection: url `jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE`

is there anyway I can execute this query in H2 and support this data type?

Comment: Consider using something like the postgresql module of testcontainers-java instead of trying to use a different database for your unit tests.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel brilliant, thank you. I tried zonky embedded Postgres but it couldn't build on Jenkins and the project does not give any actionable output, so no guidance on what went wrong. test-containers worked perfectly. could you post this as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compatibility modes like provided by H2 are not perfect, they don't provide a 100% coverage of all features, nor 100% identical behaviour.

Instead of using a different database in your unit tests, and trying to make it as close as possible (and then getting bitten by the differences in production anyway), I'd recommend using the [PostgreSQL module of testcontainers-java](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/postgres/). This allows you to spin up PostgreSQL docker images for your unit tests.

Be aware, that this will impact performance, because it will likely be a bit slower than using H2 because of the time to launch the docker image. I'd recommend to carefully consider whether your tests truly needs to go to a database, or can get away with mocking data, or at least limiting the scope of tests that (need to) go to a database.

Comment: works like a charm - I noticed the time overhead immediately, but this will live in a functional testing layer so it shouldn't be too disruptive

Answer (score 0):

The biggest question here is how your table with unknown data type was created? Column `ip_address` should have some other data type known by H2.

Actually you can create a domain like this:

```sql
CREATE DOMAIN INET AS VARCHAR;
```

But usage of the same database system everywhere would be better.

Comment: `create table myTable ( ip_address inet,  id INT NOT NULL)` is the sql used to create the table - resulting in `Unknown data type: "inet"; SQL statement` error

Comment: I ran `create domain inet as varchar` preceding the above table creation and  encounter the same error - because the return of create is false - gotta figure out why that command is failing

Comment: `create domain inet as varchar; create table myTable ( ip_address inet, id INT NOT NULL);` completes without any exceptions in H2.

Comment: I wish I was having the same luck. I am using Scalike JDBC - ```using(inMemoryPool.borrow()) { conn =>
      val db: DB = DB(conn)

      db.localTx { implicit session =>
        val inetCreated = sql"""create domain inet as varchar""".execute().apply()
        println(inetCreated) // false
        sql"""create table mytable (
                  ip_address inet,
                  id INT NOT NULL)""".execute.apply()

      }
    }```   -- result of the creation of domain is false and the subsequent create table fails

Comment: With plain JDBC and in H2 Console everything works well, but I can't help you with the wrapper that you use; I'm not familiar with it.